# Run one block of HTML Code in flutter with external link css

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I created a flutter web app. Now i have to include a html code. The flutter web app was developed in the traditional way. I have used the package: flutter_html/flutter_widget_from_html. Tried both. The problem is flutter is not reading the css link, it just displays A Global Flag without any css applied.

The whole project was coded `WITHOUT` any html code/ webview etc. Coded in dart. Now i just need to implement a portion of the html code below.

```
 const htmlData = r"""

<body>
  
      <link rel="stylesheet"href="https:....."/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:..."/>
<div class="ext_hd">
    <a href="https://...." target="_blank">
        <span class="ext-icon ext-icon-flag"></span>
        <span class="is-text">A Global Flag</span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>


""";
return Stack(
              children: [
   HtmlWidget(htmlData),
html(htmlData),])
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056122/how-to-apply-external-css-to-html-render-in-flutter-webview) helps

Comment: @jabbson I already have widgets (Stack, container, rows, buttons) i just want to add a div in a container, on top of all the widgets i have already programmed in dart. App was developed without any webviews.